# change pagination url

Tags: pagination, urls

Currently I’m having URL for pagination pages as:

http://www.example.com/category_name/page/2

But I need to change this URL structure as:

http://www.example.com/category_name/?page=2

etc.

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the format argument of wp_link_pages function like this:

```
<?php $args = array(
  'base'               => '%_%',
  'format'             => '?page=%#%',
  'total'              => 1,
  'current'            => 0,
  'show_all'           => False,
  'end_size'           => 1,
  'mid_size'           => 2,
  'prev_next'          => True,
  'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
  'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
  'type'               => 'plain',
  'add_args'           => False,
  'add_fragment'       => '',
  'before_page_number' => '',
  'after_page_number'  => ''
); ?>
```

Its works good for me

See more https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by disabling canonical redirection for pagination queryies like so...

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', function ( $redirect_url ) {

if ( is_paged() ) {
    return false;
}

return $redirect_url;

}, 10, 1 );
```

This should get you...

```
http://www.example.com/category_name/?paged=2
```

Note, this used `paged` instead of `page` as this is reserved for `multi-part` posts